# need to set value for r(radius) in the <circle> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a scatter plot with line created using D3.js (as shown in the image).
The initial value to the circle radius is set to 4 however, when `mouseover` or click event are fired on the circle it should become 6 (r=6).
Whereas I am able to achieve this in chrome as following:

```
document.getElementById('dotGain' + count).style.r = 6;
```

the same doesn't work in IE.

The HTML created as dom is:

```
<circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="dotGain" id="dotGain51" style="cursor: pointer; fill: red;" cx="440.621" cy="3.78507" r="4" />
```

I need to modify the r="4" to "6" on click/mouseOver in IE.

Some added help: 
I tried the following to achieve the required in IE, but in vain

```
document.getElementById('dotGain' + count).r.animVal.valueAsString = "6";
document.getElementById('dotGain' + count).r.animVal.value = 6;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be changing the `r` attribute, not the style; and this is wrong: `document.getElementById('#MyCircle')` because you have a hashtag in the id name.

See a working example here:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');

c.addEventListener('click', function(){
  c.setAttribute('r', 6);
})
```

```html
Click the circle
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="4" id="c"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

`r` is a element attribute. To change it You can use `jQuery`

```
$(el).attr('r', 6)
```

or in `vanilla js`

```
el.setAttribute('r', 6);
```